# SQL Join/Summarize/Fill empty columns - within one table

Tags: sql, join, summarize, metabase

I think I need a join statement but all the join information I find is for 2 tables.

I have data like this:

[image]

And the rows refer to each other like this:

[image]

I would like to combine the rows, and end up with this:

[image]

I tried it with left join and inner join.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can self join tables if you use Aliases to identify them.

```
select t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t2.Genre, t1.Title 
from myTable t1
join myTable t2 on t1.ID2 = t2.ID1
```